# A question about the associative classes of parabolic subgroups

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathbb{A}$ denote the adele group of $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are parabolic subgroups of a reductive algebraic group $G$, and consider their Langlands decomposition
$$
  P(\mathbb{A})=M_P(\mathbb{A})A_P(\mathbb{A})N_P(\mathbb{A}).
$$
We call $A$ or $\mathfrak{a}$, the Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponding to $A$, the *split component* of $P$. We call two parabolic subgroups $P_1$ and $P_2$ *associated* if there is an element of $\gamma \in G(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $Ad(\gamma)\mathfrak{a}_1=\mathfrak{a}_2$. The question is, in the adelic setting is it true that $\mathfrak{a}_1=\mathfrak{a}_2$ implies that $P_1(\mathbb{A})=P_2(\mathbb{A})$?

Comment: You are surely not asking the question you intend, since, for example, in $GL2$, the upper-triangular and lower-triangular parabolics have the same split component. Maybe some further specification is missing?

Comment: Concerning your header, I think "associated classes" is more standard than "associative classes". Anyway, this notion doesn't enter explicitly into your question at the end.    This is related to Paul's comment.   (Also, your "adele group" actually has the structure of an algebra over ℚ.)